# How to combine 2 objects so I can apply one material

Tags: mesh, materials

I'm a beginner to Blender and I'm trying to combine 2 objects in a 3D model. I want to then apply one material to the combined objects so it uniformity covers the combined objects.

I have managed to combine the 2 objects but when I add a material (a Jpeg I have) and switch to UV mode to position the material I see that the 2 meshes are still there, so it doesn't work.

As an example, I have a model of a boat. When I imported it into blender it had part of the side of the boat in one object and another part of the side of the boat in a different object. I want to combine both objects into 1 so I have a complete side of the boat under one object and then apply a material to that object that will cover the whole side of the boat. Can you please help?
[image: scene collection]
[image: UV Editing, material]
[image: Side of Boat]
[image]

Comment: please provide some screenshots to make it more understandable

Comment: For some reason, you can only see the small section of the boat in UV mode

Comment: i'm not sure to understand, if you want only one piece for your uv map, you need to make a unique mesh, when you join 2 meshes within an object you'll still have 2 meshes, if you want one unique mesh you need to merge the vertices, fill faces, etc...